# Image remains null no matter what I do

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am working on a Action Script project and no matter what I did I wasn't able to get a texture from a Atlas, in the end I had to do some quick changes that I rather not keep. Does anyone know why I cannot get a texture from the createDiabloCrashArt method with this:

```
package gameObjects
{
    import starling.core.Starling;
    import starling.display.Image;
    import starling.display.MovieClip;
    import starling.display.Sprite;
    import starling.events.Event;
    import starling.utils.deg2rad;

    public class Diablo extends Sprite
    {
        private var _type:int;
        private var _speed:int;
        private var _distance:int;
        private var _alreadyHit:Boolean;
        private var _position:String;
        private var _hitArea:Image;
        private var diabloImage:Image;
        private var diabloAnimation:MovieClip;
        private var diabloCrashImage:Image;

        public function Diablo(_ptype:int, _pdistance:int)
        {
            super();

            this._type = _ptype;
            this._distance = _pdistance;
            this._speed = GameConstants.DIABLO_SPEED;

            _alreadyHit = false;

            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
        {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

            createDiabloArt();
        }

        private function createDiabloArt():void
        { //Gets some other stuff using the same getAtlas but as MovieAnimation and works.
        }

        private function createDiabloCrashArt():void
        {
            // trace("diablo_chingo" + _type + "KO");

            if (diabloCrashImage == null)
            {
                diabloCrashImage = new Image(Assets.getAtlas().getTexture("diablo_chingo" + _type + "KO"));
                this.addChild(diabloCrashImage);
            }
            else
            {
                diabloCrashImage.texture = Assets.getAtlas().getTexture("diablo_chingo" + _type + "KO");
            }

            diabloCrashImage.visible = false;
        }

        private function hidePreviousInstance():void
        {
            if (diabloAnimation != null && _type <= GameConstants.DIABLO_TYPE_4)
            {
                diabloAnimation.visible = false;
                Starling.juggler.remove(diabloAnimation);
            }

            if (diabloImage != null) diabloImage.visible = false;
        }

        public function get type():int { return _type; }

        public function set type(value:int):void 
        {
            _type = value;
            resetForReuse();
            hidePreviousInstance();
            createDiabloArt();
        }

        public function get alreadyHit():Boolean { return _alreadyHit; }
        public function set alreadyHit(value:Boolean):void
        {
            _alreadyHit = value;

            if (value)
            {
                diabloCrashImage.visible = true;

                if (_type >= GameConstants.DIABLO_TYPE_1 || _type <= GameConstants.DIABLO_TYPE_4)
                {
                    diabloAnimation.visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    diabloImage.visible = false;
                    Starling.juggler.remove(diabloAnimation);
                }
            }
        }

        public function resetForReuse():void
        {
            this.alreadyHit = false;
            this.rotation = deg2rad(0);
        }
  }
 }
```

But it works by changing the following things:

```
private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
{
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

    createDiabloArt();
    createDiabloCrashArt();
}

private function createDiabloCrashArt():void
{
    // trace("diablo_chingo" + _type + "KO");

    if (diabloCrashImage == null)
    {
        diabloCrashImage = new Image(Assets.getTexture("Diablo1"));
        this.addChild(diabloCrashImage);
    }
    else
    {
        diabloCrashImage.texture = Assets.getTexture("Diablo1");

        //Assets.getAtlas().getTexture("diablo_chingo" + _type + "KO");
    }

    diabloCrashImage.visible = false;
}
```

I verified time and time again with debugger, trace and the like that the right parameters where reaching the function such as _type, as a matter of fact in the long method that I didn't include getting the texture I need using the above syntax worked wonderfully.

I tried to:

1. Change Image to MovieClip
2. Initialize before getting to createCrashArt
3. Getting other textures like the ones I can already display (didn't work)
4. Staring at it really hard.
5. Setting a default string for the texture.

None yielded anything until I changed the code to look like in the second snippet, the thing is that I don't get why it didn't work and I rather not depend on a quick fix that may or may not turn into a setback later.

Seriously any help to understand this would be great. I don't even care that ir is working right now I just can't for the life of me figure what was wrong in the first place.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
    public static function getAtlas():TextureAtlas
    {
        if (gameTextureAtlas == null)
        {
            var texture:Texture = getTexture("AtlasTextureGame");
            var xml:XML = XML(new AtlasXmlGame());
            gameTextureAtlas=new TextureAtlas(texture, xml);
        }

        return gameTextureAtlas;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a texture from this class based on a string key.
     * 
     * @param name A key that matches a static constant of Bitmap type.
     * @return a starling texture.
     */

    public static function getTexture(name:String):Texture
    {

        if (gameTextures[name] == undefined)
        {

            var bitmap:Bitmap = new Assets[name]();
            gameTextures[name]=Texture.fromBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        //trace("Tomando textura!");
        return gameTextures[name];
    }
```

EDIT: Assets class

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

    import starling.textures.Texture;
    import starling.textures.TextureAtlas;

    public class Assets
    {

            /**
             * Atlas de texturas. 
             */

            [Embed(source="../Witchmedia/graphics/Spritesheet/ScarletWitch.png")]
            public static const AtlasTextureGame:Class;

            [Embed(source="../Witchmedia/graphics/Spritesheet/ScarletWitch.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
            public static const AtlasXmlGame:Class;

            /**
             *  Assets de Fondo y botones.
             */

            [Embed(source="../Witchmedia/graphics/bgLayer3.jpg")]
            public static const BgLayer1:Class;

            [Embed(source="../Witchmedia/graphics/Diablo1.png")]
            public static const Diablo1:Class;

            /**
             * Cache de Texturas 
             */

            private static var gameTextures:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
            private static var gameTextureAtlas:TextureAtlas;

            /**
             * Returna una instancia del atlas de texturas.
             * @return the TextureAtlas instance (Singleton)
             */

            public static function getAtlas():TextureAtlas
            {
                if (gameTextureAtlas == null)
                {
                    var texture:Texture = getTexture("AtlasTextureGame");
                    var xml:XML = XML(new AtlasXmlGame());
                    gameTextureAtlas=new TextureAtlas(texture, xml);
                }

                return gameTextureAtlas;
            }

            /**
             * Returns a texture from this class based on a string key.
             * 
             * @param name A key that matches a static constant of Bitmap type.
             * @return a starling texture.
             */

            public static function getTexture(name:String):Texture
            {

                if (gameTextures[name] == undefined)
                {

                    var bitmap:Bitmap = new Assets[name]();
                    gameTextures[name]=Texture.fromBitmap(bitmap);
                }

                //trace("Tomando textura!");
                return gameTextures[name];
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you show the Assets class documentation? It is not from flash/starling standard namespaces.

Comment: @GuardianX  Yeah it is a custom class with embeds and a get atlas method, I'll update the post to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Can you check with this method, Give the texture declaration in a separate class, i guess it doesnt take the appropriate texture. 


public static function getAtlas(atlasNumb:uint = 1):TextureAtlas
        {
            if(sTextureAtlas[atlasNumb - 1] == null)
            {
                var texture:Texture = getTexture("AtlasTexture"+atlasNumb);
                var xml:XML = XML(create("AtlasXml"+atlasNumb));
                sTextureAtlas[atlasNumb-1] = new TextureAtlas(texture, xml);
            }
            return sTextureAtlas[atlasNumb - 1];
        }

        private static function create(name:String):Object
        {
            var textureClass:Class =  AssetEmbeds_2x;                
            return new textureClass[name];
        }


And define the textures .png and xml in a separate file called AssetEmbeds_2x.

while calling the texture define like 
Assets.getAtlas(1).getTextures("xxx"). I hope it wll
```